# Windows Authentication with Google Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, authentication

Does Google Chrome work with Windows Authentication?  We have internal websites that use Windows authentication and I'd like Chrome to not have to prompt me every time I access those sites for username/password.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It seems that it doesn't at the moment. Auto NTLM authentication is currently on their list of known issues [here](http://www.google.com/support/chrome/bin/static.py?page=known_issues.cs).

**UPDATE**: [Chrome 5 beta](http://www.google.com/landing/chrome/beta/) now supports Auto NTLM authentication :)

Comment: +1 for the update from me too! Chrome beta has now become my work browser as it also solves my Flash lockup issues as well.

Answer (score 4):

It supports windows athentication, however it does not currently support Automatic intergrated windows atuhentication see this [issue](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=19) on google code for the history.

> **What steps will reproduce the problem?**
>   1. Configure the browser to use a proxy (I use Squid 2.7/Stable 2) with
>   authentication enabled.
>   2. Chrome will prompt for a username and password to auth with the proxy.
>   3. Browsing continues normally for the session.
>
> **What is the expected result?**
>
> Integrated authentication in the
>   browser would use the current users
>   logon credentials to authenticate with
>   the proxy server.
>
> **What happens instead?**
>
> Chrome will prompt for a username and
>   password to auth with the proxy. 
>   Entering the credentials manually
>   allow the user to continue normally.

Answer (score 3):

You can now use the command line switch:

```
--auth-server-whitelist="*example.com,*foobar.com,*baz"
```

Comment: And what will that do?

Comment: It will pass along the windows credentials to the sites listed in the whitelist.