# Asking for authentication in Google Chrome every time

Tags: google-chrome, authentication

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Windows Authentication with Google Chrome](https://superuser.com/questions/10801/windows-authentication-with-google-chrome)

Every time I open Google Chrome on my Dell vostro 1520 laptop the browser asks for authentication (even after I've already chosen the save password option). It's annoying.

Is there any way to avoid this?

Comment: Sounds like: http://superuser.com/questions/10801/windows-authentication-with-google-chrome

Comment: Thanks .
But, Nothing is there in that above mentioned post.
Can anyone check this?