# Login to site with Windows Authentication through a browser other than IE

Tags: windows, browser, authentication

When I try to access my company's web application through a browser other than IE, I am getting a Windows Authentication error: "Database connection failed for COMPANY\USERNAME. Login failed for user 'NT AUTHORITY\ANONYMOUS LOGON'". To me this indicates something with SQL Server, but I am uncertain what that something is. If anyone could assist with what the issue is and how it can be resolved, it would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your browser does not support Windows Integrated Authentication, and is connecting as an anonymous user. The database is doing the right thing and rejecting access to anonymous users.

Have you tried Google Chrome? It's [supposed to have support for Windows Integrated Authentication.](https://superuser.com/questions/10801/windows-authentication-with-google-chrome)

Comment: Thank you Darth, actually Google Chrome is what I am trying. A couple co workers have managed to get it to work with Firefox, they said they did it so long ago though they're not certain how they did it. I appreciate your response!